# What is the cycle of server side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model of name Student

```
public class Student
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }       
    }
```

My question is that, does form is submitted and then validations are checked or there is another mechanism that post hidden form values to the server side validations ?

Comment: [Adding Validation to the Model](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model)

Answer (score 0):

Generally in web development, validation occurs both client side and server side.

You want to scrub the forms for any unwanted data or characters before they are submitted, and you want to check them / scrub them again server side to ensure nothing is being passed that is unwanted.

Comment: I am talking about server side, if i had disabled javascript for the client side then how it's going to work

Comment: There is a ton of documentation about server side validation and data scrubbing for almost every server side language there is. Generally, the client side validation is done as an extra layer of security since anyone can turn off or disable javascript. No matter what, if you are accepting data through a server it needs to be scrubbed before anything happens with it so you would want to scrub whatever comes through immediately. Your initial question is not worded very well and it is not entirely clear what you are asking.